# update thinking sphinx index in ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have app, which run's on ubuntu 12.04, with nginx+passenger
And in my method i try to rebuild sphinx index so:

```
  def update_sphinx_index
    Rails.application.load_tasks
    Rake::Task['ts:rebuild'].invoke
    redirect_to admin_mainpage_path
  end
```

also i try:

```
`rake ts:index`
```

but nothing happend, sphinx index doesn't rebuild. What i do wrong? Maybe i need to do this with some privilegies, or something else, becouse when i do rake ts:rebuild in command terminal all is fine, and index rebuild.

Comment: may be you need set `RAILS_ENV`?

Comment: @Monk_Code what do you mean? code?  Rake::Task['ts:rebuild RAILS_ENV=production'].invoke

Comment: I indexation during limited hours following command `bundle exec rake ts:index RAILS_ENV=staging` on staging

Comment: @Monk_Code write all command code, which is in ruby file

Comment: but i think this bad practice reindex on controller.

Comment: @Monk_Code and which is good?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41186/discussion-between-monk-code-and-brabertaser1992)

Comment: Why do you need to update the index so often?

Comment: What happens if you run `\`rake ts:index\`` from `rails console`?

Comment: @np_ http://pastebin.com/3huSNetQ

Comment: What is the output of `\`rake ts:index`\` when you run it from within your app? For example, in a view, do `<%=\`rake ts:index\`%>`.

Comment: @np_ i get http://pastebin.com/gXGDTHVa  with =`cd /home/prog/OnlineAuto/Shop rake ts:rebuild` i get empty with rebuild http://pastebin.com/9scaKzgW

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I did not -1 your question. I +1'd because someone else gave you -1 for no good reason. But for that extreme reaction don't expect any help.

Comment: @Popnoodles really sorry...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I don't really like the idea of calling sphinx reindex from a controller. The best practice here would be to use deltas for partial indexing (deltas with resque are a great solution for almost real time indexing) and then an occasional reindex once in a while to compact the files.

But if for any reason you really need to run this from the controller, I would say there are two things to consider. One is you are probably not on the right directory, so you can try to issue the system call changing to the directory then executing rake, as in

```
`cd /path/to/your/app rake ts:index`
```

Apart from this, if you are following best practices, the user executing your web server will be an underprivileged user, something like a user belonging to the www-data group. It's very likely this user won't have permissions to execute rake or to write the index files, so make sure the user starting your web server has the right permissions.

Comment: and how can i change thid permission's? i use nginx + passenger

Comment: first you need to identify which permission issues you have. If your problem is you can't write the files, you can just make the index files available for any user in your system, as they are not really a security risk. If your problem is you can't execute rake, then you should add group permissions with chmod and make sure the user starting your web server is a part of the same group.

Answer (score 3):

`ts:rebuild` stops sphinx, rebuilds the index and then restarts, and should only be run if you've changed the structure of your index.

Instead, you should be running `ts:index` if you're only adding new data.

As for why the rake task is not executing, it may be that your search daemon is still running.

Comment: As for why the rake task is not executing, it may be that your search daemon is still running.  how to be than

Comment: You could create another task to kill the searchd process, and run it before calling `ts:rebuild`. [See here](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/497#issuecomment-17140584) for an example of such a task.

Comment: how about   Rails.application.load_tasks
    Rake::Task['ts:stop'].invoke
    Rake::Task['ts:index'].invoke
    Rake::Task['ts:start'].invoke ?

Comment: maybe there are any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using `ts:index` instead? Or killing the searchd process before running `ts:rebuild`?

Comment: first yes,  killing no

Comment: so first i need to create task with code: task :kill_searchd do
  run 'ps -ef | grep "searchd.*<application/folder>" | grep -v grep | awk \'{print $2}\' | xargs kill'
end  and then run it in controller before "thinking_sphinx:rebuild", "kill_searchd" ?

Comment: Yeah something similar to that.

Comment: i try with killing process, and it didn't help

Comment: what else could you propose?